# External command download progress output writes zillion lines in PowerShell remote session

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

*Note: I do not know if this choco specific issue or not (probably not), but this is the only scenario when I can demonstrate it*

**Context**

I use an external command (this case choco) in my PowerShell script. When the command displays progress (not with the PowerShell top [ooooo....]) then in the standard output in the last line the progress overwrites itself so the final output is always one line.

When I run the very same script in a remote context like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock {
    & "./myscript.ps1" # <-- This is the script where the external choco executes
}
```

then the local PowerShell output is flooded with zillion separate lines of one updating line like this:

> Progress: 0% - Saving 128 KB of 43.81 MB
>   Progress: 0% - Saving 287.99 KB of 43.81 MB
>   Progress: 0% - Saving 432 KB of 43.81 MB
>   Progress: 1% - Saving 591.99 KB of 43.81 MB
>   Progress: 1% - Saving 751.98 KB of 43.81 MB
>   Progress: 2% - Saving 911.97 KB of 43.81 MB

This is not only disturbing, it overflows the command window buffer also, what I set the maximum 9999.

**Question**

Is it by design, or is there a setting something about new line or similar in remote case?

Comment: It seems to me like some issue with a carriage return character (`\r`). It usually used to output data in the same line.

Comment: Do you mean in case of remote the \r is processed differently (incorrecly)? Is there any configuration what has effect on this?

Comment: Yes, that's my assumption. But I've tried to run remotely this `1..10| % {write-host "$_\`r" -NoNewline;sleep 1}` and it worked just as expected. Try it in your environment and tell if it's worked for you. Unfortunately I have no clue about what could affect this.

Comment: Instruct the external command to not show progress or redirect its output to a file. Problem solved.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, about redirect output yes that's a KISS solution, but even I accept to lose the progress feedback information, all other information will also lost.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/chocolatey-configuration#features): `choco feature disable -n showDownloadProgress`. And what do you mean by "lost"? If you're redirecting output to a file you can download the file afterwards to get access to the redirected output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers. You are right, thx. I did not find this choco feature, because I was looking for the install command switch...